# App + Web Measurement ID and the /collect Endpoint

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

TL;DR: How does the Measurement ID in the new App + Web Tracking feature work with the /collect endpoint?

We use the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol to send app events to our customers' Google Analytics instances. An anonymized example of a URL we'd make a GET request to is below:

> `https://google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-TEST&ds=app&an=BRANCH-APP&t=event&ec=BranchEvent&cid=&cn=Test&cs=test&cm=test&ck=&cc=&ea=INSTALL&uip=1.2.3.4&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Linux%3B%2028%3B%20Dalvik%2F2.1.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+9%3B+moto+g%287%29+play+Build%2FPPYS29.105-134-9%29%20Build%2FIMM76B%29%20AppleWebKit%2F535.19%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F8.0.1025.133%20Mobile%20Safari%2F535.19%20%5BBranch%20Webhook%5D&z=1584644783123`

I'm trying to figure out how this works with the new App + Web tracking feature GA recently announced. According to their implementation guide, this uses a Measurement ID which replaces the Tracking ID:

- Tracking ID: UA-XXXXXX-YY
- Measurement ID: G-XXXXXXXXXX

We can't find any documentation on what should change with how we're hitting the /collect endpoint for customers using App + Web Tracking. Does it replace the Tracking ID in the call? Do we make a different call entirely? Does the call stay the same and continue to work?

Any help is much appreciated!

Docs Referenced Above:
App + Web Tracking: https://www.blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/new-way-unify-app-and-website-measurement-google-analytics/

Implementation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/app-web/tag-guide

Comment: While I cannot point do any documentation, I tried to come up with a part answer to a similar question. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59264782/analytics-track-custom-events-in-new-webapp/59268126#59268126

Answer (score 2):

You are using using measurement protocol v1 (see parameter `v=1`), however App+Web uses a new version of the measurement protocol, **version 2**, that for the moment it has not yet been documented.

Comment: There is some information here about v2 however very limited  https://www.thyngster.com/technical-overview-of-new-appweb-properties/

Answer (score 0):

I faced such issues. There are not only changes between Tracking ID and Measurement ID but also there is a question about how to get a Client ID and new parameter as a Session ID, also there is another endpoint for collect, there is "/g" added in url.

I found that the necessary parameters are: v, tid, cid, sid, sct, dl, and sure en.
Details on what are those parameters are and how to get them: https://lunaxod.com/measurement-protocol-v2-google-analytics-appsweb/